# How to remove Price symbol

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to know how to remove price symbol only Shopping cart total page. I tried but i don't know exactly file location

[image]

Comment: If you remove the currency sign from the file, it will also remove from other pages where grand total is displayed. Have you tried to do this by javascript?

Comment: no i didn't try js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find bellow files your magento fronted design folder

app\design\frontend\xyz\default\template\tax\checkout

- grandtotal.phtml
- subtotal.phtml
- discount.phtml

and **replace bellow function from**

```
$this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getTotal()->getValue());
```

**TO**

```
Mage::helper('core')->currency($this->getTotal()->getValue(), false, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all currency codes in lib/Zend/Locale/Data/xx.xml
changing xx.xml to your country letters .xml e.g. us.xml

But to remove the symbol from the cart, you should override the block or helper that call

```
 public function getCurrencySymbol($code)
```

To remove from all website go to:

System > Manage Currency > Symbols

Comment: i know this i want to only remove in shopping cart page